# How to easily parse the AT command response from a GSM module?

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I'm trying to parse the following output taken from a GSM module in Arduino, to get the Voltage (`3.900V`) part only. However, I can't get it to work.

```
"    
+CBC: 0,66,3.900V

OK
"
```

I have tried the following code, but it fails and even crashes.

```cpp
    float getVoltage() {
        if (atCmd("AT+CBC\r") == 1) {
            char *p = strchr(buffer, ',');
            if (p) {
                p += 3; // get voltage 
                int vo = atof(p) ;
                p = strchr(p, '.');
                if (p) vo += *(p + 1) - '0';    // ??
                return vo;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

How can this be done in a better or more transparent way?

Comment: You could use regular expressions, but a strrchr at the `,` might work as well.

Comment: Well, there are 2 `,`s and it's possible that the `66` can be 1-3 digits. Not sure RE is the best way here. The above code is some legacy stuff I don't quite follow. I guess a better option would be to read from the end of the second line, because there are always 1+3 digit and a `V`.

Comment: I.e. Find `V` and read the 5 characters before that.

Comment: what is `atCmd` and `buffer`?

Comment: @Juraj It is a function that send the AT command and the buffer the response is received in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the C function [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to tokenize the buffer

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  char buffer[20]  = "+CBC: 1,66,3.900V";

  const char* delims = " ,V";
  char* tok = strtok(buffer, delims); // +CVB:

  tok = strtok(NULL, delims);
  int first = atoi(tok);

  tok = strtok(NULL, delims);
  int second = atoi(tok);

  tok = strtok(NULL, delims);
  float voltage = atof(tok);

  Serial.println(first);
  Serial.println(second);
  Serial.println(voltage);

}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: That is actually a nicer way to do it, as it can be used for several variables and other AT responses.

Comment: sscanf would work too, but would take 1kB flash for the scanf implementation

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```cpp
    float getVoltage() {
        if (atCmd("AT+CBC\r") == 1) {
            char *p = strchr(buffer, 'V');
            if (p) {
                p -= 5;  // get voltage
                double vo = atof(p) ;
                //printf("%1.3f\n", vo);
                return vo;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```